# Grid parameter restriction of mpl_toolkits.basemap.maskoceans

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have plotted the image below with the use of `matplotlib` and `mpl_toolkits.basemap`. However I am not satisfied with the result. The image is still very blocky near the coast line. The `grid` parameter of the `maskoceans` method seems to be the issue, however the API doesn't allow a lower grid size. How can I work around this restriction and why did they made this restriction? I guess you don't have this problem for larger countries.

[image]

Here a part of the code I used:

```
xArray = np.array(xArray)
yArray = np.array(yArray)
heightArray = np.array(heightArray)
xmin, xmax = 3.3, 7.3
ymin, ymax = 50.7, 53.5

numIndexes = 1000
xi = np.linspace(3.3, 7.3, numIndexes)
yi = np.linspace(50.7, 53.5, numIndexes)
zi = ml.griddata(xArray, yArray, heightArray, xi, yi, interp='linear')

m = Basemap(projection = 'merc', llcrnrlon = xmin, llcrnrlat = ymin, urcrnrlon = xmax, urcrnrlat = ymax, resolution='h')
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1)

xx, yy = m(np.array(xi), np.array(yi))
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zi = maskoceans(xi, yi, zi, resolution = 'h', grid = 1.25, inlands=True)
m.drawlsmask(land_color='grey',ocean_color='white', grid=1.25, resolution='h')
m.pcolormesh(xx, yy, zi, cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'), vmin=0, vmax=100)
plt.colorbar()
```

---

To clarify what I would like even more I added the image below. This image was edited by a photo editor and is not something what `matplotlib` produced directly.

[image]

Comment: Can you use shapefiles to mask anything, which is not the Netherlands?